# How to make only 5 slides visible at a time in corousel.js based slider

Tags: javascript, css

This is the slider i am trying to use.  I have more then 25 slides which i want includewhen i am trying to do that its dynamically shrinking the image size and fitting almost 10 slides on page i only want to see 5 slides at any given time

Any Fix for this on how to get only 5 slides on Visible html page

Comment: 3.s3.envato.com/files/37836635/index4.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is phrased in a very confusing manner. Can you explain a bit better please? I see what looks like 3 slides at once, in a 3d look